# Как правильно включить/выключить кнопку при выделении элемента QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, qt-designer, qpushbutton, pyqt6, qtreewidget

Нарисовал в *Qt Designer* себе *GUI*, в нем есть простейший одноуровневый `QTreeWidget` и несколько не активных `QPushButton` (снял галочку `enabled` в *Qt Designer*).

Хочу, чтобы при выделении строки (когда один раз левой кнопкой мыши) в `QTreeWidget`, мои `QPushButton` становились активны, а при исчезновении фокуса (к примеру, если выделенную строку удалить) - обратно отключались.

Вроде бы, это надо делать через подключение какого то сигнала из `QTreeWidget` в ... куда? 
Писать отдельную функцию про включение/выключение кнопок? Или есть более простые решения?

Т.к. ни у кого перед глазами готового **`QTreeWidget`** не нашлось, закидываю текст .py файлов:

**ui_one_button.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(502, 180)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(254, 214, 188);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Baby_Groot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled(False)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.Baby_Groot.setFont(font)
        self.Baby_Groot.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);")
        self.Baby_Groot.setObjectName("Baby_Groot")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Baby_Groot, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Groot = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Groot.setObjectName("Groot")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Groot)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Groot)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Groot)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Groot, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 502, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.mf_Open = QtGui.QAction(parent=MainWindow)
        self.mf_Open.setObjectName("mf_Open")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Baby_Groot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Baby Groot"))
        self.Groot.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Groot.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.Groot.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.Groot.isSortingEnabled()
        self.Groot.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(2).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        self.Groot.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.mf_Open.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
```

**main_one_button.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui_one_button import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # self.Groot.[что то?].connect(self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled())
        # self.Groot.[что то?].connect(self.Baby_Groot.setDisabled()) # хотя вот это и не обязательно, выключать кнопки можно и с того кто удаляет строку, да.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Собственно, что писать заместо [квадратных скобок]?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick да как бы проблемы нету, просто не понимаю какой сигнал брать у treewidgetа и куда его втыкать. Но если надо могу через пару часиков нарисовать нулевой gui с одним виджетом и одной кнопкой.

Comment: @S.Nick закинул текст примеров. Как сделать так, чтобы потыкав в Грута получить Бэйби-Грута?

Comment: @S.Nick По возможности, глянь пожалуйста на оптимальность того, что я наФранкенштейнил в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
#from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from ui_one_button import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(502, 180)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F5DEB3;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Baby_Groot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled(False)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.Baby_Groot.setFont(font)
        self.Baby_Groot.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FF69B4; color: #7CFC00;")
        self.Baby_Groot.setObjectName("Baby_Groot")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Baby_Groot, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.Groot = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Groot.setObjectName("Groot")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Groot)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Groot)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Groot)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Groot, 1, 0, 6, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 502, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
  
# ???        self.mf_Open = QAction(parent=MainWindow)      # ???
# ???        self.mf_Open.setObjectName("mf_Open")          # ???

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Baby_Groot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Baby Groot"))
        self.Groot.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Groot.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.Groot.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.Groot.isSortingEnabled()
        self.Groot.setSortingEnabled(False)
        
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item 0"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item 1"))
        self.Groot.topLevelItem(2).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item 2"))
        
        self.Groot.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
# ???        self.mf_Open.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))    


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Groot.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.onSmthChanged)
        self.Baby_Groot.clicked.connect(self.onBabyClicked)

    def onSmthChanged(self, *args):
        if self.Groot.selectedItems():
            self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled(True)
            self.Baby_Groot.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: rgb(127, 255, 0); color: #006400;")
        else:
            self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled(False)

    # Удаляем выбранный элемент из списка
    def onBabyClicked(self):
        QTreeWidget.invisibleRootItem(self.Groot).takeChild(
            self.Groot.currentIndex().row())

        items = self.Groot.selectedItems()       
        [it.setSelected(False) for it in items]
        self.Baby_Groot.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FF69B4; color: #7CFC00;")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Хм, надо будет как окажусь за компьютером попробовать протестировать, как оно отреагирует на попытку выделить чтобы удалить `New Item 2` сразу после удаления `New Item 1` - если я ткну сразу в `New Item 2` станет ли кнопка снова активна, или придется ткнуть в 0, и лишь потом в 2?

Comment: Про `# ???` - я же удалил меню Файл и его пункт `mf_Open` в `qt Designer`е, откуда оно тут взялось?

Comment: PS Кажется понял, это вы там `for it in items` снимаете выделение со всего что только можно?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 пожалуйста. Да, вы все правильно поняли.

Comment: я тут положил отдельным вопросом про то что и у вас вопросы вызвало... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537285/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%b2-qt-designer%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c

Answer (score 0):

Ок, вроде как сам до чего то дотыкался. У меня вроде как работает. 
Сверху добавил простенькую функцию, при нажатии кнопки удаляет выделенный элемент.

Изменения только в файле **main_one_button.py**:

```
import sys

# Добавился импорт QTreeWidget'а:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeWidget

from ui_one_button import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

# два коннекта - первый обрабатывает изменение выбранного элемента в Груте, второй - клик на Бэйби Грута:
        self.Groot.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.onSmthChanged)
        self.Baby_Groot.clicked.connect(self.onBabyClicked)

    def onSmthChanged(self):
# Если для Грута существует выбранный элемент - включаем кнопку, иначе - выключаем.
        if self.Groot.selectedItems():
            self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.Baby_Groot.setEnabled(False)

# Удаляем выбранный элемент из списка
    def onBabyClicked(self):
        QTreeWidget.invisibleRootItem(self.Groot).takeChild(self.Groot.currentIndex().row())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```